# how can i change the default theme of spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, themes, frontend, spree

I installed the Spree rails app, but I do not like the default theme! and I want to change it, I'm trying to install a gem from [here](https://github.com/vinsol-spree-contrib/spree_themes) but does not work, does anyone have a suggestion? Are there themes to buy or free ?

Answer (score 0):

Spree comes with Bootstrap by default, so you can implement any theme by yourself. As I know, in Spree there are not many themes available like other platforms but [spree_themes](https://github.com/vinsol-spree-contrib/spree_themes) is a good start